# TypeScript enum values error TS2749: 'FOO' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof FOO'?

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript function which takes a enum value:

```
type TPosition = 'LEFT' | 'RIGHT';
function position(position: TPosition) {
  //
}
```

If I try and move the enums to be constants (as I want to use them elsewhere) I get an error:

```
const LEFT = 'LEFT';
const RIGHT = 'RIGHT';
type TPosition2 = LEFT | RIGHT;
function position2(position: TPosition2) {
  //
}
```

> TS2749: 'LEFT' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof LEFT'?

It's an easy fix, but why is this needed? I would expect `LEFT` and `'LEFT'` to be identical, but this must not be the csae?

```
type TPosition2 = typeof LEFT | typeof RIGHT;
```

Comment: If there is something you don't understand about this you should ask a question. The compiler already tells you what you should do to avoid the error.

Comment: But why dont use proper enums?

Answer (score 2):

```
enum TPosition {
    LEFT = 'LEFT',
    RIGHT = 'RIGHT'
}
```

```
function position2(position: TPosition) {
    //
}
```

You can also access the enums like so:

```
console.log(TPosition.LEFT)
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

I agree with MrCodingB though. google your error, google how to define enums in TypeScript.